# Group array by value php

Tags: php, json, slim

After selecting all the values from the table into a result array

```
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I  want to created an array that contains groups for same session dates

**mysql table**
[image]

Then pass it as JSON.

How do we group the result by session dates?

Something like this but instead of the dates "2018-04-01:" if it can be replaced with 0 and then 1,2...
**Result something like this**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code helped me group the arrays

```
if($objects)
        {
            $grouped = array();
            foreach($objects as $object) {
                if(!array_key_exists($object->id, $grouped)) {
                    $newObject = new stdClass();
                    $newObject->id = $object->id;
                    $newObject->title = $object->title;
                    $newObject->contents = $object->contents;
                    $newObject->follow_up_link = $object->follow_up_link;
                    $newObject->created_at = $object->created_at;
                    $newObject->ITEMS = array();
                    $grouped[$object->id] = $newObject;
                }
                $taskObject = new stdClass();
                $taskObject->news_id = $object->news_id;
                $taskObject->extension = $object->extension;
                $taskObject->resource_link = $object->resource_link ;
                $grouped[$object->id]->ITEMS[] = $taskObject;
            }

    $grouped = array_values($grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your sql query and use the GROUP BY  clause

Or possibly php array_values

```
<?php
    print_r(array_values($result));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking is more about the request than the result array.
Can you edit your post to specify the request you have ?

In SQL, there is a "GROUP BY" parameter in order to make groups.

```
Select * From Table GROUP BY `sessions_title`
```

Comment: The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.